# How to include all characters but whitespace in elasticsearch simple_query_string?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for the simplest query system in elasticsearch, in which the only separator is the whitespace. I would like to query usernames in text that comes with pretty much all types of characters, e.g. @username or @u$er-na_me

It thought that this was going to be easy, but only after a long search I found a "whitespace" analyzer:

`query.json:`

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "@username",
        "fields": ["mytextfield"],
        "analyzer": "whitespace",
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

which, I run with: `curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/my.index/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@query.json'`

However, it returns nothing.

Other details:

- `"query": "username"` still works
- If I remove `"analyzer": "whitespace"`, then I get the same results for `"query": "username"` and `"query": "@username"`
- I have seen similar posts in SO (e.g. [Simple query string with special characters such as ( and =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877483/simple-query-string-with-special-characters-such-as-and)) in which they seem to create new indices or mappings. If this is the way to go, I would appreciate some resources to understand the workflow.

So, to summarize, is there any easy way to configure elasticsearch or a query to only tokenize using whitespaces (and ideally basic punctuation marks)?

Comment: Hi @toto_tico can you please share your mapping? Is your field analyzed with the whitespace analyzer?

Comment: The fact that I barely understand your question makes me think that I don't analyze the field with the whitespace analyzer. But, it makes sense;  `mytextfield` also needs to be analyzed a priori: I have read something about the standard analyzer but changing it is not straight forward. How do I share you my mapping?

Comment: In the meantime, I have worked out the tokenizer that I would like to use  is char_group: `"tokenizer": { "type": "char_group", "tokenize_on_chars":["whitespace", "\n", ".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "\"" ]}`. I am still figuring out how to put all of this together, but ES has a lot of concepts that are not easy to digest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toto_tico, you need to analyze your field(s) and to specify it in your mapping like below :

1) Index creation with a single analyzed field :

```
PUT totoindex
{
  "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "mytextfield":{"type":"text", "analyzer": "whitespace"}
        }
      }
    }
}
```

2) Indexing some sample document :

```
POST totoindex/_doc/
{
  "mytextfield": "@toto_tico"
}
```

3) Searching the document :

```
POST totoindex/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "@toto_tico",
        "fields": ["mytextfield"]
    }
  }
}
```

Response :

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "totoindex",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "MtorKW8BavUEUOqEr6k_",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "mytextfield": "@toto_tico"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @baitmbarek, I also read that I cannot change the current index, so it should be a new one. In reality, I never create any index, I just used monstache to migrate my data from mongoDB to elasticsearch. That creates the index automatically, and I am guessing it uses the default analyzer/tokenizer. This give me a good idea of what to try, but it will take me a while to put the stuff together (I am working with big mongo collections). It also seems that I should change the tokenizer instead of the analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Although @baitmbarek provides the general/quick answer to the question, it requires some understanding of the problem. Hence, I will try to provide a simplified answer to the question from a newbie perspective.

## First indexing, then searching!

Now, that I say it; I feels so obvious [1]. If you want the search happening in certain way, the index should be created in such way.

## Once indexed, there is no way back

**Not absolutely true**, you can create a new index and then an alias. **However, no way back** is generally the case from a newbie perspective.

## Get familiar with the elastic search nomenclature

Here is a list to for this particular post: indexes, documents, analyzer, tokenizer, mappings.

Certainly, there is [glossary](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html), and a [guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html)

## The steps

1. Delete your current index, and the data that you currently have

```
curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/YOUR_INDEX"
```

2. Create the index with the characteristics that you need. Here is the one for my question (whitespaces and simple punctuation marks)

2.1. For ElasticSearch 7

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/[MY_INDEX] -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "MY_TOKENIZER": { 
                      "type": "char_group", 
                      "tokenize_on_chars":["whitespace", "\n", ".", ",", ";", ":", "\"", "`", "]", "[", ")", "(", "!", "?", "/", "\\", "–", "<", "<", "|", "+", "=", "~", "-", "&", "%", "*", "^", "\u0027"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "MY_ANALYZER": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase"],
                    "tokenizer": "MY_TOKENIZER"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "MY_TEXT_FIELD":{"type":"text", "analyzer": "MY_ANALYZER"}
        }
    }
}
'
```

2.2 For ElasticSearch 6:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/[MY_INDEX] -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "tokenizer": {
                "MY_TOKENIZER": { 
                      "type": "char_group", 
                      "tokenize_on_chars":["whitespace", "\n", ".", ",", ";", ":", "\"", "`", "]", "[", ")", "(", "!", "?", "/", "\\", "–", "<", "<", "|", "+", "=", "~", "-", "&", "%", "*", "^", "\u0027"]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "MY_ANALYZER": {
                    "type":      "custom",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase"],
                    "tokenizer": "MY_TOKENIZER"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "MY_TEXT_FIELD":{"type":"text", "analyzer": "MY_ANALYZER"}
        }
      }
    }
}
'
```

3. Insert your documents

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/[MY_INDEX]/_doc/
{
  "MY_TEXT_FIELD": "here is @toto_tico!"
}
```

4. And search as usual (no need to specify anything here; `MY_TEXT_FIELD` was indexed with `MY_ANALYZER` so it knows how to be searched):

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/MY_INDEX/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "@toto_tico",
        "fields": ["MY_TEXT_FIELD"]
    }
  }
}
```

[1] Honestly, the query system of elastic search is so non-newcomers-friendly (very powerful for sure, but bulky and with a steep learning curve), that it is easy to forget what is happening here. Elasticsearch works out-of-the-box, and later on you realize that out-of-the-box is not what you need.